# error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

```
//define
typedef std::vector<double> vertex_data;

//serialise
std::ostringstream oss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss); 
vertex_data data = .......get_data();//returns vertex_data
oa & m_state & data;//send this data over network

//deserialise
std::istringstream iss(recvd_msg);
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss); 
vertex_data data;
ia>>data; //error here
```

Why am I getting this error during deserialisation?

Comment: Because... `serialize` is not a member of std::vector.

Comment: but stl containers are already serialisable by boost, arent they?

Comment: Try including `<boost/serialization/list.hpp>`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you have no special serialization for std::vector defined, so it falls back to the default serialization, which tries to call a member called serialize on the class to be serialized.

To get the special code for std::vector, you need to include `<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>`, as described here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#models

Comment: Thanks! I was dreading having to split my vector up for transmission

Answer (score 0):

To deserialise using a boost serialiser you need to use the operator&, like you are for serialisation.

```
std::istringstream iss(recvd_msg);
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss); 
vertex_data data;
ia & data;
```

Comment: >> also works for deserialising, but I tried & and get the same error